# Bulk loading data to GridGain (attempting through REST endpoint but 414 URI too long)

Tags: gridgain

Looking to bulk load data into the cache through a REST interface. I am currently looking at the REST example which uses a Jetty server. In escene, something similar to what Elasticsearch's bulk loading API performs http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html.

I have tried posting ~ 30 records through the REST endpoint mylocalhost:8080/gridgain?cmd=putall and would receive a "414 Response code, URI too Long"

I am open to other methods, I am just looking for a way to stream lots of data to the (and always have the connection remain open) and the bulk loading API seemed appropriate but I couldn't even load ~30 records

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to make GET request. In this case all key-value pairs will be appended to URL, so it will be too long. You should configure your client to use POST method instead.